# Updating object in array hook react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopping-cart

I trying to update the quantity by pressing the "up" button.

This is my code.

```
const increaseHandler = (x) => {

    let newCart = [...props.cartItems];

    let exist = newCart.find((item) => item.id === x.id);
    if (exist) {
        exist.quantity++;
    } else {
        exist = {
            ...props.cartItems,
            quantity: 1,
        };
    }
    newCart.push(exist);
    props.setCartItems(newCart);
};
```

Here is the button:

```
<button className="up" onClick={() => increaseHandler(items)}>
    up
</button>
```

Every time I click on the "up" button, it appends a duplicate of the item on the cartItems

[image: Image for initial cartItems]

[image: Image for the problem after increasing the quantity here]

I increased the quantity but it appends the object to the array.

Comment: ```newCart.push(exist)``` should be inside the else block.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've shallow copied the cart items array you are still mutating the individual items with the post increment.

```
const increaseHandler = (x) => {
    let newCart = [...props.cartItems];

    let exist = newCart.find((item) => item.id === x.id);
    if (exist) {
        exist.quantity++; // <-- mutation!!
    } else {
        exist = {
            ...props.cartItems,
            quantity: 1,
        };
    }
    newCart.push(exist); // <-- adds duplicate items
    props.setCartItems(newCart);
};
```

You still need to create a new item reference, shallow copying the properties and updating the `quantity` property. You should only push ***new*** elements into the cart array.

```
const increaseHandler = (x) => {
    const newCart = [...props.cartItems];

    let exist = newCart.find((item) => item.id === x.id);
    if (exist) {
        exist = {
            ...exist,
            quantity: exist.quantity + 1;
        };
    } else {
        exist = {
            ...props.cartItems,
            quantity: 1,
        };
        newCart.push(exist);
    }
    
    props.setCartItems(newCart);
};
```

It's more common to map the previous state to the next state, and I suggest using a functional state update to ensure correctly updating from the previous state versus any state closed over in callback scope (*possibly stale*).

```
const increaseHandler = (x) => {
  props.setCartItems(items => {
    const inCart = items.some((item) => item.id === x.id);
    if (inCart) {
      return items.map((item) => item.id === x.id 
        ? {
          ...item,
          quantity: item.quantity + 1,
        } 
        : item);
    }
    return items.concat({
      ...props.cartItems,
      quantity: 1,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update by using `map`:

```
const increaseHandler = (x) => {
  props.setCartItems((preState) =>
    preState.map((item) => (item.id === x.id ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 } : item)),
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the entire `cartItems` array into the single `exist` object you've created. So you're adding the entire cart to `exist` and then setting `exist.quantity` to be `1`, and pushing that whole thing into `newCart` and setting it into state.

Try spreading `exist` rather than `props.cartItems` in your `else` block.

Based on your images and nomenclature, is this the FreeCodeCamp/Wiebenfalk tutorial on react & TS? If so, I did the same tutorial, and here's my add to cart function:

```
const handleAddToCart = (clickedItem: CartItemType) => {
setCartItems((prevState) => {
  // check if item is in cart by looking for id of clicked item in array of cartItems already in state
  const isItemInCart = prevState.find((item) => item.id === clickedItem.id);
  if (isItemInCart) {
    // search for item id matching clicked item; increment that amount
    return prevState.map((item) =>
      item.id === clickedItem.id
        ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 }
        : item
    );
  }
  return [...prevState, { ...clickedItem, amount: 1 }];
});
};
```